# 'None' or 'Not Used' foreign key when using GUIDs as primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, guid

We are building an application that may need to be replicated to many servers (I'm hoping not, but there's no way to know if clients will need their own client/server copy until after we release the online product).

Since the number of servers is unknown, I've decided to use GUIDs for any transactional table IDs.  Since each client has their own database, I intend to use the NEWSEQUENTIALID() default, and the largest table will add no more than 1.5M rows per year (but on average 15K rows), I don't expect much of a performance problem.

However, I'm not sure how to handle cases where we want the foreign key to indicate 'none selected'.  For example, a client has a single admin user.  This is set up as a foreign key (login_id) to login.id (a GUID).  However, if a client doesn't yet have an admin user, how would we easily set up a "None Selected" key?

In prior applications we used IDENTITY columns, and inserted a dummy entry in most tables with an ID of 0.  Is there an accepted approach to providing similar functionality with a GUID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1) In your referenced table, add the blank value row with a guid of all zeros, then link to this record

2) Just store a null for the blank references

3) Don't have the blank records in the reference table, but store an all zero guid.  This may cause problems if joins are done in in the database, or with reports.  You'll have to code for this special case.

I'd say 1 and 2 are the only good options.

Comment: I disagree with option 1, any special case is a special case and are problems waiting to occur. Option 2 is widely used and proven.

Answer (score 4):

The only safe way to do this, is set the FK value to NULL. If you need to replicate data between multiple servers, make sure each table that you replicate has GUIDs as their primary keys, foreign key relationships are this way never a problem.

Replication can work very simple this way: replicate inserts and updates first in the order of parent to child table, after that replicate the deleted records from child to parent. (reverse order.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something really obvious here, but can't you just set it to NULL?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who thought this was trivial. Maybe we ARE missing something.

Comment: For us, it has always been much easier to deal with 0's in code than to deal with NULL values.

Comment: Whats wrong with Null? I use null FK's and I haven't had any problems

Comment: LuckyLindy, what problems have you had with NULL values in the past? Even if that's true, it's no reason not use them in this case.

Comment: Alex - SQL statements can be more cumbersome (i.e. to check for a user selected value of 'None' you have to do a "is null", which means 2 different SQL statements), also you have to code for NULLable types (or worse if you're using a language that doesn't support them).  0s eliminate these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make the foreign key field in the child table NULLable and keep the field NULL when there's no admin user. Magical values like "0" identity columns is a disaster waiting to occur.

Comment: How so?  Isn't it easier to deal with 0's in code than NULLs?  Years ago we tried writing an app where foreign keys could be NULL, and it was a bear.  We've since written many apps using 0 as the foreign key constraint and never had a single problem.

Comment: Fake rows are MUCH harder to deal with than != NULL. With the advent of Nullable<T>, there isn't any problem any more.